# library path for setup.py?

Tags: python, numpy, setup.py

When trying to build numpy on a linux platform, I can't make the configure script look in the right place. 
I use

```
python setup.py config --library-dirs=/software/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/
```

but then I get

> mkl_info:
>     libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /software/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025
>     libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /software/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/include
>     libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /software/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib

So it looks like it never actually looks into the subdirectory emt64/. The path I'm giving is also present in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

How can I give the script the right path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `site.cfg` file look like?

Comment: are you sure the python executable you are using is 64 bit? try: file `which python`

Comment: Had a similar problem with another package. My gotchas were; 1) make sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set and exported, and 2) using sudo drops environment's LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so 'setup.py bdist' as regular user, and 'sudo setup.py install' (if you install as root at all).

Comment: If you want to tell `pip install` where to find external libraries see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942120/1843329

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with rpy2.  Did not have root permissions and could not alter the existing R installation or add to its core library directory.  R was not built as a shared object library, so I could not link the rpy2 build to a libR.so.

I had to cross compile libR.so on a separate machine (same R version, same Linux family) and copy it to a different directory.  I wanted that directory to be seen by setup.py.

Couldn't get -L to work on the command line.  It appeared that this argument was deactivated.

(FAIL)  python setup.py -L${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} build install

What I ended up doing was editing setup.py and changing a line that accepts library directory entries.

(old) r_libs = []

(new) [os.path.join('/root','path','to_my','install','R','lib'),]

Reran it as:  python setup.py build install

Success!

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps

```
export PYTHONLIB="/software/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/"
python setup.py config
```