# python pip specify a library directory and an include directory

Tags: python, shared-libraries, pip, include-path, pyodbc

I am using pip and trying to install a python module called pyodbc which has some dependencies on non-python libraries like unixodbc-dev, unixodbc-bin, unixodbc. I cannot install these dependencies system wide at the moment, as I am only playing, so I have installed them in a non-standard location. How do I tell pip where to look for these dependencies ? More exactly, how do I pass information through pip of include dirs (gcc -I) and library dirs (gcc -L -l) to be used when building the pyodbc extension ?

Comment: Was python installed with the [`--user`](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme) option?

Answer (score 130):

pip has a `--global-option` flag

You can use it to pass additional flags to `build_ext`.
For instance, to add a --library-dirs (-L) flag:
`pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/path/to/local" pyodbc`

gcc supports also environment variables:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html

I couldn't find any build_ext documentation, so here is the command line help

```
Options for 'build_ext' command:
  --build-lib (-b)     directory for compiled extension modules
  --build-temp (-t)    directory for temporary files (build by-products)
  --plat-name (-p)     platform name to cross-compile for, if supported
                       (default: linux-x86_64)
  --inplace (-i)       ignore build-lib and put compiled extensions into the
                       source directory alongside your pure Python modules
  --include-dirs (-I)  list of directories to search for header files
                       (separated by ':')
  --define (-D)        C preprocessor macros to define
  --undef (-U)         C preprocessor macros to undefine
  --libraries (-l)     external C libraries to link with
  --library-dirs (-L)  directories to search for external C libraries
                       (separated by ':')
  --rpath (-R)         directories to search for shared C libraries at runtime
  --link-objects (-O)  extra explicit link objects to include in the link
  --debug (-g)         compile/link with debugging information
  --force (-f)         forcibly build everything (ignore file timestamps)
  --compiler (-c)      specify the compiler type
  --swig-cpp           make SWIG create C++ files (default is C)
  --swig-opts          list of SWIG command line options
  --swig               path to the SWIG executable
  --user               add user include, library and rpath
  --help-compiler      list available compilers
```

Comment: I wish this were better documented. This was pretty much the only thing that worked for me, installing scikit-learn against a statically compiled ATLAS, combined with option-specification as described [here](http://scikit-learn-general.narkive.com/FSKFd98i/on-building-scikit-learn-0-14-1-with-static-atlas-on-non-standard-location)

Comment: I found `--install-option` also worked instead of `--global-option` for specifying paths to libraries. I'm not sure when one should be used rather than the other though.  Maybe `--install-option` only applies to install and `--global-option` has a wider scope. See also https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-install-option

Comment: If you want to include multiple libraries or include directories, they are separated by a *semi*-colon, not a colon.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to specify a path that is relative to the build directory that PIP temporary creates while it's running.

Comment: If you're wondering how to get the command line help, run `python setup.py build_ext --help` in the directory with the setup.py file.

Comment: `--global-option` is now deprecated, is it possible to do this with `--config-settings`? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1

Answer (score 39):

Building on Thorfin's answer and assuming that your desired include and library locations are in /usr/local, you can pass both in like so:

```
sudo pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include/" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib"  <you package name>
```

Answer (score 26):

Another way to indicate the location of include files and libraries are set relevant environment variables before running pip e.g.

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
pip install cryptography
```

Comment: Wow, this is really great; it also helps when doing `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py bdist_wheel`!

Comment: In my case I needed to add  `CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/...../include` too.

Answer (score 13):

Just FYI... If you are having trouble installing a package with pip, then you can use the

`--no-clean` option to see what is exactly going on (that is, why the build did not work). For instance, if numpy is not installing properly, you could try

`pip install --no-clean numpy`

then look at the Temporary folder to see how far the build got. On a Windows machine, this should be located at something like:

`C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Bob\numpy`

Just to be clear, the --no-clean option tries to install the package, but does not clean up after itself, letting you see what pip was trying to do.

Otherwise, if you just want to download the source code, then I would use the `-d` flag. For instance, to download the Numpy source code `.tar` file to the current directory, use:

```
pip install -d %cd% numpy
```

Answer (score 5):

I was also helped by Thorfin's answer; I was building GTK3+ on windows and installing pygobject, I was having difficulties on how to include multiple folders with pip install.

I tried creating pip config file as per pip documentation. but failed.
the one working is with the command line:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IlistOfDirectories" 
# and/or with:  --global-option="-LlistofDirectories"
```

the separator that works with multiple folders in windows is **';' semicolon**, NOT colon ':' it might be different in other OS.

sample working command line:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-Ic:/gtk-build/gtk/x64/release/include;d:/gtk-build/gtk/x64/release/include/gobject-introspection-1.0" --global-option="-Lc:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\lib" pygobject==3.27.1
```

you can use '' or '/' for path, but make sure do not type backslash next to "

this below will fail because there is backslash next to double quote

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-Ic:\willFail\" --global-option="-Lc:\willFail\" pygobject==3.27.1
```

Comment: What about windows paths? What is default and how to write them?

Answer (score 0):

In order to indicate the location of the include files and libraries on Windows using the Visual Studio Compiler (MVSC) you can specify them as environment variables, too.

In powershell, type

```
$Env:INCLUDE='path\to\include'
$Env:LIB='path\to\libs'
```

before running the installation via pip.

More information on the environment variables used by MVSC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#path_and_environment

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever used [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)? It's Python package that let's you create and maintain multiple isolated environments on one machine. Each can use different modules independent of one another without screwing up dependencies in your system library or a separate virtual environment.

If you don't have root privileges, you can [download and use the virtualenv package from source](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#installation):

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py myVE
```

I followed the above steps this weekend on Ubuntu Server 12.0.4 and it worked perfectly. Each new virtual environment you create comes with PIP by default so installing packages into your new environment is easy.

Comment: James, indeed. In the answer I have given I should have specified that I have used virtualenv as well.

Comment: This doesn't really help, since the OP clearly stated that they need to install non-python libraries (i.e. pass args to the compiler/linker).  I'm actually in the same boat, and I'm a little frustrated that every third answer to this question is "use virtualenv", because (while I agree that virtualenv is a great tool) it doesn't really address this problem.

Comment: @gred, after a closer look at the question, I agree...virtualenv isn't the right solution here. Looks like the OP found a workaround with by using setup.py.

Comment: I am not sure how this remotely helps the OP.  This looks like a pitch for using virtualenv

Comment: @vivekv If you had read the comments previous to yours, you'd see that this point was already made and subsequently acknowledged by me

Answer (score -2):

Just in case it's of help to somebody, I still could not find a way to do it through pip, so ended up simply downloading the package and doing through its 'setup.py'. Also switched to what seems an easier to install API called 'pymssql'.

Comment: how did you point setup.py to the dependencies you installed in the non-standard location?

Comment: like this `python setup.py build_ext --rpath=/usr/local/lib` ?