# pip install customized include path

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install a library `pyleargist`. It requires another lib `libfftw3` to be manually installed which I've installed. Since I don't have the root privilege, I have to install `libfftw3` under my home directory: `~/usr/include` and `~/usr/lib`. Then I follow this post: https://superuser.com/questions/242190/how-to-install-matplotlib-on-os-x, added:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L~/usr/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I~/usr/include
```

So that `pip` knows it have to consult `/usr` to get the include (*.h files) and lib (*.a, *.so files). However, while running `pip install --user pyleargist`, it complains about:

```
gcc-4.4.real: src/leargist.c: No such file or directory
gcc-4.4.real: no input files
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I guess what happened is that the path is incorrect so that it can't find the `*.c` files (I think `pip` should have downloaded the file somewhere but not sure where it is).

So my questions are the following: 1) in this particular case, how can I install `pyleargist` with `include` and `lib` path under `~/usr`? 2) more generally, how can one provide additional path for `pip` so that it knows where to get the additional include files or libs if not found in the default path?

p.s I am on an `ubuntu` machine without `sudo` privilege.

ref: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyleargist/1.0.1 
http://www.fftw.org/

Comment: how did you go? Do you have all the missing dependencies in ~/usr/..? Are the versions you've got there compatible with dependencies installed on the system?

Comment: @drevicko Yes. There is only on dependency and I put it in `~/usr/`. They are compatible. I know it because I can install it on other machines where I have `sudo` privilege.

Comment: What's the `gcc` command that generated the error? Also the location of `leargist.c` and if it exists somewhere in your `~/usr/` or elsewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pip specify a library directory and an include directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783390/python-pip-specify-a-library-directory-and-an-include-directory)

Comment: Ironically, on my mac arm trying to install `pyopencl` I had the same error regarding a missing `Python.h` file. But in my case the problem was fixed by the `export CFLAGS=-I/whatever` approach. The `--global-option="-I/whatever"` approach failed miserably. So thanks for the question!

Answer (score 34):

`pip` has a `--global-option` flag

You can use it to pass additional flags to `build_ext`.

For instance, to add a `-I` flag:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/home/users/abc/include/" pyOpenSSL
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a helpful thread. Just to add on to this, you can also use pip without root if you pass the `--user` flag at the end:

```
pip install --global-option="-I/home/users/abc/include/" mpi4py --user
```

For example, if you're using python-v2.7, the above command installs the python package to `/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have root you can get a [virtual enviroment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) no root is needed to get one and your path will be in home

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
python virtualenv.py myVE
```

then your path is set in your home:

```
cd myVE/bin
./python

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/foobar/temp/virtualenv-1.10.1/myVE/lib/python33.zip', '/home/foobar/temp/virtualenv-1.10.1/myVE/lib/python3.3', '/home/foobar/temp/virtualenv-1.10.1/myVE/lib/python3.3/plat-linux', '/home/foobar/temp/virtualenv-1.10.1/myVE/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.3', '/usr/lib/python3.3', '/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-linux', '/home/foobar/temp/virtualenv-1.10.1/myVE/lib/python3.3/site-packages']
>>>
```