# "fatal error: sql.h" with unixODBC and pyodbc as a vendor app dependency

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to add unixODBC as a vendor app dependency, as per notes that are outlined here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/issues/34, but I'm still getting fatal error:

> sql.h: No such file or directory.

I've created a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete script below to facilitate readers with reproducing my issue:

```
mkdir new_app
cd new_app

cat <<EOF>requirements.txt
pyodbc==4.0.17
EOF

cat <<EOF>manifest.yml
applications:
 - name: pyodbc-test
   memory: 128M
EOF

cat <<EOF>.profile
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/vendor/unixodbc/lib
EOF

sudo docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/app cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2 bash -c \
   "wget ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.4.tar.gz;  tar xzf unixODBC-2.3.4.tar.gz; cd unixODBC-2.3.4;  ./configure --prefix=/app/vendor/unixodbc; make; make install;"
```

Followed by:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} vendor/
pip3 download -r requirements.txt -d vendor/
cf push
```

The cf push output:

```
...
-------> Buildpack version 1.5.15
 !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Cloud Foundry how to run your application.
 !     Learn more: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/prod-server.html#procfile
-----> Installing python-2.7.13
Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpack/dependencies/https___buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org_dependencies_python_python-2.7.13-linux-x64.tgz]
     $ pip install -r requirements.txt
       Collecting pyodbc==4.0.17 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
       Installing collected packages: pyodbc
         Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
           Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
           Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sxxn23/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lRnuMu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
           running build
           running build_ext
           building 'pyodbc' extension
           creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
           creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.17 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c src/errors.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/errors.o -Wno-write-strings
           cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
           In file included from src/errors.cpp:2:0:
           src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
            #include <sql.h>
                            ^
           compilation terminated.

           ----------------------------------------
           running install
           creating build
           error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sxxn23/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lRnuMu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sxxn23/pyodbc/
Failed to compile droplet
Exit status 223
Staging failed: Exited with status 223
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container
```

There is a similar question here: [pyodbc install on IBM Bluemix server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962872/pyodbc-install-on-ibm-bluemix-server-error), however that question is different to this question in that it is very generic, whereas this question is on the same topic but relates to a very specific set of build steps.

---

**Update:**  Here is the updated script based on the accepted answer:

```
mkdir new_app
cd new_app

cat <<EOF>environment.yml
name: pyodbc-test
dependencies:
- pyodbc
EOF

cat <<EOF>manifest.yml
applications:
 - name: pyodbc-test
   memory: 128M
EOF

cf push
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory #include

Your setup generally looks OK, but when `pip` runs during staging the build tools are still unable to find the library headers.  The headers are there since you're including them in the `vendor/` directory, but it doesn't know they're there as the build script for the python module won't look for them in that location.

I don't know of a way to make it look for the headers in a non-standard location without modifying the build pack because [you need to send additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28981343/1585136) to `pip`.

A few people suggested setting the `CPATH` and/or `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variables as these are supposed to get picked up by `gcc`, but in my tests, these were ignored.

In the end, I think your best bet is to use Conda to install pyodbc.  Here's how you'd go about that.

1. Add `environment.yml` to the root of your project.
2. In it add the following:

```js
name: pyodbc-test
dependencies:
- pyodbc
```

3. Run `cf push`.

The build pack should run during staging, install miniconda and then install your dependencies with conda, specifically pyodbc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

As per @Daniel Mikusa's answer...

> you need to send additional arguments to pip.

Pip supports `--global-options` to pass this sort of thing along. Unfortunately, from here the options are passed to setup.py.

setup.py has it's own option for globals which is `build_ext`...

```
Options for 'build_ext' command:
  --build-lib (-b)     directory for compiled extension modules
  --build-temp (-t)    directory for temporary files (build by-products)
  --plat-name (-p)     platform name to cross-compile for, if supported
                       (default: linux-x86_64)
  --inplace (-i)       ignore build-lib and put compiled extensions into the
                       source directory alongside your pure Python modules
  --include-dirs (-I)  list of directories to search for header files
  ...
```

Setup.py needs `build_ext --include-dirs <path to unixodbc/include>`

As far as I'm aware, to give those arguments to setup.py each argument must be individually prepended by `--global-option=`.

I just went through the same headache, and the following worked for me.

```
pip install pyodbc --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--include-dirs" --global-option="<path to unixodbc/include>"
```