# Error in DjangoCMS setup

Tags: django-cms

I installed DjangoCMS using pip but when I try to launch:

> djangocms -p . myapp

to create a new project with DjangoCMS and I answer all the setup questions I get this error:

> Command /home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hYUC5s-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/include/site/python2.7 failed with error
>   code 1 in /home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/build/Pillow Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/bin/djangocms",
>   line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('djangocms-installer==0.5.0', 'console_scripts', 'djangocms')()   File
>   "/home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py",
>   line 25, in execute
>       install.requirements(config_data.requirements)   File "/home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/**init**.py",
>   line 64, in requirements
>       exit_status = pip.main(args)   File "/home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/**init**.py",
>   line 185, in main
>       return command.main(cmd_args)   File "/home/b.esque/Escritorio/eb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 161, in main
>       text = '\n'.join(complete_log) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.0.4. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with pillow and python headers.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
pip install pillow
```

After this follow this intructions if you get this error:

```
EnvironmentError: Pillow is not compiled with JPEG support, see 'Libraries installation issues' documentation section.
```

[Getting error while running django-cms demo page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078303/getting-error-while-running-django-cms-demo-page#23086541)