# getting error when creating a new django-cms project

Tags: pip, django-cms

I want installing django-cms, but when I want create a new project with this code

```
>>djangocms -p . my_demo
```

I get this error:

```
(myLibrary)Mehradads-MacBook-Pro-3:Workspace mehradad$ djangocms -p . my_demo

Database configuration (in URL format) [default sqlite://localhost/project.db]: 
django CMS version (choices: 2.4, 3.0, stable, develop) [default stable]: 
Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, stable) [default stable]: 1.5.8
Activate Django I18N / L10N setting (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Install and configure reversion support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Languages to enable. Option can be provided multiple times, or as a comma separated list. Only language codes supported by Django can be used here: en
Optional default time zone [default America/Chicago]: 
Activate Django timezone support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Activate CMS permission management (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Use Twitter Bootstrap Theme (choices: yes, no) [default no]: yes
Use custom template set [default no]: 
Load a starting page with examples after installation. Choose "no" if you use a custom template set. (choices: yes, no) [default no]: yes
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org

Command /Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/v5/gzrs3m_932x8gfpqc5lt6kh00000gn/T/pip-3JZJJw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/build/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/mehradad/.pip/pip.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 25, in execute
    install.requirements(config_data.requirements)
  File "/Users/mehradad/Web_project/Workspace/myLibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 64, in requirements
    raise InstallationError("Error while installing requirements. Check pip log file for error details.")
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Error while installing requirements. Check pip log file for error details.
```

I don't know why i get this error!
I create this project in max osx 10.8.5

Can anybody help me whith this problem!?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found correct solution:

first install :

```
$ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
```

then set setting prior value for environment:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

then install pillow by pip :

```
$ pip install pillow
```

now install djnago project:

```
$ djangocms -p . mysite
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm running on Ubuntu, so my setup is a bit different.  But basically I looked at pip.log file (cat ~/.pip/pip.log), and found that my machine was missing necessary files for compilation, so I had to do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

And (based on what I found [on another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078303/getting-error-while-running-django-cms-demo-page#23086541)):

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
```

Since you are on MacOS, your situation will be a bit different, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: by your solution and extra link I found this solution

Answer (score 1):

In addition to comment of Mehrdad Faraji.

If you are using Maverics (Mac OS)

Just install:

```
xcode-select --install
```