# Error while using Django CMS installer

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm following Django-CMS's quick start tutorial. When trying to setup the project using `djangocms -f -p . mysite`, and using recommended settings, when it's installing the required dependencies it comes with this pip error:

```
`Command "c:\users\kasper\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Kasper\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9abaaes2\\django-cms\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Kasper\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-91wvs4yy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Kasper\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9abaaes2\django-cms\`
```

I'm on windows, and not sure what it means, nor how to fix it.

The solutions to the other question don't work on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error when creating a new django-cms project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185104/getting-error-when-creating-a-new-django-cms-project)

Comment: @thanksd I see it's the same error, but the solutions don't work on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: Upon further investigation I see that my error is slightly different.

Comment: Could you post pip.log and file C:\Users\Kasper\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-91wvs4yy-record\install-record.txt? Looks like a failed compilation, maybe due to some missing binary library