# raise ImportError 'PILKit was unable to import the Imaging Library'

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

when i try to install PIL on my ubuntu server in virtualenv it is throwing this error

```
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3qvaiv6l/PIL
```

however i have pillow installed. even then it is showing this error in error.logs

```
[Mon Mar 30 16:24:14.892127 2015] [:error] [pid 31004:tid 139913894803200] [client 122.167.116.201:57073]     raise ImportError('PILKit was unable to import the P$
$n Imaging Library. Please confirm it`s installed and available on your current Python path.
```

What is the case here and how should i proceed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078303/getting-error-while-running-django-cms-demo-page/23086541#23086541

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available" - PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil)

Comment: seems that the error i am getting is entirely different from these two links

Comment: First install Pillow not pill, then the error you are receiving is that Pillow is not actually installed, what was the output of your installation?

Comment: Yes I have installed Pillow in my virtuaenv and have cross checked it this is the output:  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in ./myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages

Comment: even PIL is showing in site-packages

Comment: Did PIL compile properly? it doesn't matter if it is installed, what matters is if the proper packages where compiled, as I said, try what i posted and then revisit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer. the problem was occuring because thewsgi.py file was not having the python path for the virtual environment in appropriate way.