# Django-cms Fail to create project following tutorial Creating the projectFailure occurred

Tags: python, django, centos, django-cms, centos7

Using CentOS 7 and tried to follow the tutorial but failed.

I used virtualenvwrapper.

```
mkvirtualenv env
```

Then I followed the tutorial.

before creating project.

```
(env)[***@*** ~]$ python -V
Python 3.4.3
(env)[***@*** ~]$ pip list
pip {7.1.2)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

Installing djangocms-installer:

```
(env)[***@*** ~]$ pip install djangocms-installer
Collecting djangocms-installer
  Using cached djangocms_installer-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from djangocms-installer)
  Using cached six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip in ./.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from djangocms-installer)
Collecting tzlocal (from djangocms-installer)
Collecting argparse (from djangocms-installer)
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dj-database-url (from djangocms-installer)
  Using cached dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from tzlocal->djangocms-installer)
  Using cached pytz-2015.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, pytz, tzlocal, argparse, dj-database-url, djangocms-installer
Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0 dj-database-url-0.3.0 djangocms-installer-0.8.0 pytz-2015.6 six-1.9.0 tzlocal-1.2
```

creating Project:

```
(env)[***@*** ~]$ mkdir tutorial-project
(env)[***@*** ~]$ cd tutorial-project/
(env)[***@*** tutorial-project]$ djangocms -p . mysite
Database configuration (in URL format) [default sqlite://localhost/project.db]:
django CMS version (choices: 2.4, 3.0, 3.1, stable, develop) [default stable]:
Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, stable) [default stable]:
Activate Django I18N / L10N setting (choices: yes, no) [default yes]:
Install and configure reversion support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]:
Languages to enable. Option can be provided multiple times, or as a comma separated list. Only language codes supported by Django can be used here: en, de
Optional default time zone [default America/New_York]: America/Chicago:
Activate Django timezone support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]:
Activate CMS permission management (choices: yes, no) [default yes]:
Use Twitter Bootstrap Theme (choices: yes, no) [default no]: yes
Use custom template set [default no]:
Load a starting page with examples after installation (english language only). Choose "no" if you use a custom template set. (choices: yes, no) [default no]: yes
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
Dependencies installed
Creating the projectFailure occurred. Do you want to cleanup by removing /home/***/tutorial-project? [Y/N] N
```

The directory is empty no matter I typed Y or N but with N comes the following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 31, in execute
    install.check_install(config_data)
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 55, in check_install
    raise EnvironmentError("\n".join(errors))
OSError: Pillow is not compiled with JPEG support, see 'Libraries installation issues' documentation section: http://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/libraries.html

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/env/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 57, in execute
    "http://djangocms-installer.rtfd.org\n" % e).with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 31, in execute
    install.check_install(config_data)
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 55, in check_install
    raise EnvironmentError("\n".join(errors))
OSError: Pillow is not compiled with JPEG support, see 'Libraries installation issues' documentation section: http://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/libraries.html
Documentation available at http://djangocms-installer.rtfd.org
```

pip list after failing to create the project:

```
dj-database-url (0.3.0)
Django (1.7.10)
django-classy-tags (0.6.2)
django-cms (3.1.3)
django-reversion (1.8.5)
django-sekizai (0.8.2)
Django-Select2 (4.3.1)
django-treebeard (3.0)
djangocms-admin-style (0.2.8)
djangocms-column (1.5)
djangocms-file (0.1)
djangocms-flash (0.2.0)
djangocms-googlemap (0.3)
djangocms-inherit (0.1)
djangocms-installer (0.8.0)
djangocms-link (1.7.0.dev1)
djangocms-picture (0.1)
djangocms-style (1.5)
djangocms-teaser (0.1)
djangocms-text-ckeditor (2.6.0)
djangocms-video (0.1)
html5lib (0.9999999)
Pillow (2.9.0)
pip (7.1.2)
pytz (2015.6)
setuptools (18.2)
six (1.9.0)
tzlocal (1.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

I tried

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel freetype-devel zlib-devel
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078303/getting-error-while-running-django-cms-demo-page#23086541), specifically the CentOS comment, may be of use to you.

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-devel libpng-devel zlib-devel
```

Also, based on comments, you may need to uninstall and reinstall Pillow.
See this [related post on Pillow errors for DjangoCMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078303/getting-error-while-running-django-cms-demo-page#23086541).

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed the above three packages. I also upgraded pillow following the related post. Still the same error.

Comment: Oh. I followed the second answer in your link and it solved my problem. Thanks.