# Pip install global-option"-I<library path> Option -I is not recognised

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I am installing a python module that require compilation inside a conda environment.  The base installation fails because pip is not looking for the Python.h file in the proper location.  To fix this, I have found I need to tell it the include path using --global-option
My command is

```
pip install -e . --global-option="-I/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/fitrm/include/python3.7m"
```

This returns an error

```py
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [6 lines of output]
        usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
           or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
           or: setup.py --help-commands
           or: setup.py cmd --help
        
        error: option -I not recognized
        [end of output]
```

I have found that others have  [similar errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276861/pip-install-global-option-l-library-path-option-l-not-recongnised) but received no answers.

Any thoughts of suggestions will be helpful.