# How to link libraries to OpenCL.lib when pip installing a python package, using developer command prompt?

Tags: linker, opencl, amd-gpu, viennacl

I am on a Dell Inspiron laptop with an AMD graphics card and am aiming to install a python package named `pyviennacl`:

https://github.com/viennacl/pyviennacl-dev

I am using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019.

When I run:

```bash
pip install pyviennacl
```

The following error message is returned:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'OpenCL.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

Now, I really have no idea how to proceed. I can see what the error is but cannot find any help.

I've tried to install various Intel/AMD OpenCL packages to remedy this issue, however, to be completely honest, I do not know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

did you had a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783390/python-pip-specify-a-library-directory-and-an-include-directory/22942120#22942120) ?

Also, I resolved the same issue by defining the `LIB` environment variable to the directory containing the "OpenCL.lib" file (by default at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\lib\x64` for NVIDIA graphic card. It can be different for AMD or Intel GPU).

In summary, `PATH` is where your binary will look for `.dll` files at runtime. To tell link.exe where to look for your `.lib` libraries you need to configure the `LIB` environment variable instead. (source [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/problem-linking-libraries-on-windows/15238))