# add external system dependancie library to searched path of pip install

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install scipy. The installation need acces to some system librarie, and it fails in step 2 `Getting requirements to build wheel` of installation:

```
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error 
..
    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/gnu/store/abznl1yzi6isa57mh1mj3fsdylksqd7m-python-3.8.2/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
```

I have installed openblas, but it is in `~/.guix-profile/lib`.
How I can add the path to pip?

I have try -L option as indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783390/python-pip-specify-a-library-directory-and-an-include-directory), but it fails directly in step 1 `Installing build dependencies` instead of step 2

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user --global-option="-L$HOME/.guix-profile/lib" scipy 
/home/dev_1/.guix-profile/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py:243: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
..
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
```

Comment: Does it help if you add back the other library paths to the `-L` option?

Comment: with `--global-option="-L$HOME/.guix-profile/lib:/gnu/store/abznl1yzi6isa57mh1mj3fsdylksqd7m-python-3.8.2/lib:/usr/lib"`, it fails in step 1 with same error also